# ScriptListener code creates new layer above active layer

Tags: photoshop, extendscript, photoshop-script

I've used the scriptlistener to create a new layer. The clever thing it does is places it above the active layer (without moving it from the top after creation) However, I'm at a loss to work out which part of the code it is since they all get complied with executeAction:

```
function create_new_layer(layername)
{
    var idMk = charIDToTypeID( "Mk  " );
    var desc447 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idnull = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
    var ref217 = new ActionReference();
    var idLyr = charIDToTypeID( "Lyr " );
    ref217.putClass( idLyr );
    desc447.putReference( idnull, ref217 );
    var idUsng = charIDToTypeID( "Usng" );
    var desc448 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idNm = charIDToTypeID( "Nm  " );
    desc448.putString( idNm, layername );
    var idLyr = charIDToTypeID( "Lyr " );
    desc447.putObject( idUsng, idLyr, desc448 );
    var idLyrI = charIDToTypeID( "LyrI" );
    desc447.putInteger( idLyrI, 57 );
    executeAction( idMk, desc447, DialogModes.NO );
}
```

Comment: But this is a default Photoshop behaviour: new layers are created on top of the active one. Am I missing something?

Comment: `var layerRef = app.activeDocument.artLayers.add();` creates a layer at the top of the stack, but Layers > New Layer creates one on top of the active layer. You would have thought that the two would do the same thing.

Comment: Copy and paste that bad boy and I'll accept it as the best possible answer ツ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think AM code represent actual functions in Photoshop, how they work inside, and DOM is some kind of overlay on top of that. Generally DOM code is limited and can't do a lot of things AM can. In this case `ArtLayer.add()` pushes a layer to `activeDocument.layers` so it appear on top of the layers stack, while AM command executes `New Layer...` command. Also generally AM code works much faster than DOM (up to 10-15x), especially with things like selecting layers and working with them.